# Ember.js property initialization explanation

Tags: ember.js

I'm just getting started with Ember and come across this issue while writing some jasmine tests.

Given I have the following code

```
App.RecipeController = Ember.Controller.extend
  selectedGrain: null
  amount: null
  recipeGrains: Ember.A()

  totalWeight: (->
    weight = 0
    @get('recipeGrains').forEach (grain) ->
      weight += grain.get('weight')
    weight
  ).property('recipeGrains.@each')

  addGrain: ->
    grain = Ember.Object.create
      name: @get('selectedGrain').get('name')
      weight: parseFloat(@get('amount'))
    @get('recipeGrains').pushObject(grain)
    @set('selectedGrain', null)
    @set('amount', null)
```

And I write the following test.

```
describe("Controllers", function() {
  describe("NewRecipeController", function() {
    var controller;

    beforeEach(function() {
      controller = Brewery.NewRecipeController.create();
    });

    it("calculates the correct total weight", function() {
      var grains = controller.get('recipeGrains');
      grains.pushObject(Ember.Object.create({weight: 4.0}));
      grains.pushObject(Ember.Object.create({weight: 3.2}));
      expect(controller.get('totalWeight')).toEqual(7.2);
    });

    it ("adds grains based on its selected grain", function() {
      controller.set('selectedGrain', Ember.Object.create({name: "Wheat"}));
      controller.set('amount', '10.2');
      controller.addGrain();
      expect(controller.get('totalWeight')).toEqual(10.2);
    });
  });
});
```

I expected that both tests would pass, but instead the second test fails with the message

> Expected 17.4 to equal 10.2.

It seems the state of the first test is spilling over the the second test.  Can someone more knowledgeable than I pelase explain how Ember handles controller states and why this happens?

Thank you!

Comment: I renamed the question, for more clarity & better indexation...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why your test fails is the default value initialization @ line 4.

You should either set the initial value in `init` method in `App.RecipeController` or passing the value at instance creation:

```
App.RecipeController = Ember.Controller.extend
  init: ->
    @set 'recipeGrains', Ember.A()
```

or

```
controller = Brewery.NewRecipeController.create({ recipeGrains: Ember.A() });
```

You should have a look to [section 6 of this article](http://codebrief.com/2012/03/eight-ember-dot-js-gotchas-with-workarounds/).

Comment: Thank you for the great article! This helps a lot.